# edit Style dropdown in "Create Div Container" to be different than Styles pulldown

Tags: ckeditor

I can edit my ckeditor.styles.js file to add styles to my Styles dropdown list. And when I use the "create div container" button, they show up in the dropdown list, too. But I don't want them to.  I want to create unique styles for the div button. If you use some of the styles from the styles pulldown, and you have more than one html element, they wrap each element with the style. I need to be able to wrap a group of elements with one div wrapper that uses a unique style. Is there any way to do this?